# Tags Suggestion Box?

Tags: discussion

I am using this "[suggestion box](http://tomcoote.co.uk/JavaScript/JSONSuggestBox/demo.html)" on my test site and I love everything about its look/feel.  But, the only problem the payload is HUGE.  The data file it uses is 757kb.

As evidence by my reputation, I'm a newbie here and I like the suggestion box you use for tags.  I was wondering if the kind folks at stackoverflow could post a tutorial on how the tags suggestion box works.

Comment: So, going from the data file size, are you bringing all the data to the client and filtering it there? If so, you might want to look into AJAX -- then the client can send a very small request and the server can handle all the data.

Comment: @mmy, is it me or we need a belongs on stackoverflow close reason for this question? :)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt they'd do that.

You'd have better luck asking programming questions on http://stackoverflow.com to build your own, it shouldn't be so hard (although you don't specify your programming experience).

It would also be acceptable to ask there if anyone knows of a better one, in regards to performance. A drop down suggestion thingy is quite common.